# Find all cells that include specific text in another cell, then return those cells in another column of the same row as the specified cell

Tags: excel, if-statement, search, indexing

I need to find a way in Excel to do something like below:

```
+------+-------+-----------------+
| COL1 | COL2  |      Col3       |
+------+-------+-----------------+
| A    | A_1   | A_1, A_2, A_3   |
| C    | A_2   |                 |
| B    | D_1_A | B_1, B_2, B_2_A |
| E    | B_1   |                 |
| F    | B_2   |                 |
| D    | B_2_A | D_1_A           |
| G    | A_3   |                 |
+------+-------+-----------------+
```

1. Specify the values in each cell of `COL1`
2. In `COL2`, find all cells that include the values in `COL1`
3. In `COL3`, in a single cell matching the row index of `COL1`, return all the cell values from `COL2` that include the values of the cells in `COL1`

The wording of the question is confusing but I hope the table makes more sense. I tried numerous IF, SEARCH, INDEX, and VLOOKUP functions but failed to do this correctly. Please note that the list isn't in any particular order (I can't list it alphabetically as the underscores in the cell values mess up other formulas in the workbook). Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: for COL3 you will need Office 365 excel, sort your data on Col2 and a helper column, or vba.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If VBA is an option, then you could write your own UDF, that can achieve, what you would liek to achieve.

Copy this into a Module:

```
Function ConStr(a As Range, b As Range) As String

Dim r As Range

For Each r In a
    If r.Value <> "" And Left(r.Value, 1) = b.Value Then
        If ConStr = "" Then
            ConStr = r.Value
        Else
            ConStr = ConStr & " " & r.Value
        End If
    End If
Next r

End Function
```

Then you would use the Function like this:
In Col3 put this formula

```
=ConStr(B$1:B$7,A1)
```

and drag down as far as you need.

If VBA is not an Option, then Scott already pointed in the right direction.